# Is it the correct way to invoke the templatized class from the implementation in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am invoking the templatized class from the actual implementation.

**templatized class:**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <list>
    
    template <typename Argone, typename Argtwo>
    class CTestImpl
    {
    
    public:
        void CTestImpl::handleEvents(Argone f_strID, Argtwo f_obj)
        {
           m_hvar->sendEvents(f_strID, f_obj);
        }
    };
```

**Actual implementation:**

```
    string l_strID;
    shared_ptr<CMainImplone> l_hCallObj = nullptr;
    
    shared_ptr<CTestImpl<string, shared_ptr<CMainImplone>>> l_listObj = nullptr;
    l_listObj->handleEvents(l_strID, l_hCallObj);
```

If I want to invoke from another class like `CMainImpltwo` with `int` parameter, can I do like as shown below:

```
    int l_iD;
    shared_ptr<CMainImpltwo> l_hCallObj = nullptr;
    
    shared_ptr<CTestImpl<int, shared_ptr<CMainImpltwo>>> l_listObj = nullptr;
```

Is it the correct way to invoke the template class from the implementation like this?

Comment: Do note that `l_listObj->handleEvents(l_strID, l_hCallObj);` has undefined behavior as you are calling a member function on a null pointer.

Comment: Your example isn't valid code. You can't define `CTestImpl::handleEvents` as an inline function in the class body -- which makes it look like you might be defining this out-of-line, which is only fine if `handleEvent`'s definition is visible from the point of the template's instantiation

Comment: Please provide [mcve] and describe what kind of  functionality you are trying to achieve, since for me this looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).